# Delete records from one table using join with another table?

Tags: sql-server

Delete records from one table using join with another table.
Ok, the mission is to delete all employee records if in the title of their department can be 
found word "sales". It can happen in the real life. Imagine that newlly elected CEO decides 
to close all sales operations.

this my Query:

```
DELETE *
FROM Employees
WHERE DeptNo IN
  (SELECT DeptNo
  FROM Departments
  WHERE LCase(DeptName) LIKE '*sales*')
```

but i got error. SQL Syntax error.Please help me.

Comment: In addition to the unnecessary `*` after `DELETE`, if you're using SQL Server, you should not be using `LCase()`, or `*` in wildcards. Are you sure this is SQL Server and not Access?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the star! The syntax (see the **[`DELETE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)** page at MSDN), can be either:

```
DELETE
FROM Employees
...
```

or

```
DELETE Employees
FROM Employees
...
```

or

```
DELETE e
FROM Employees AS e
...
```

You probably don't need the stars in the `'*sales*'` string either. If you mean to find the rows with `'sales'` string anywhere in that column, the wild card is `%` (see the **[`LIKE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)** page):

```
DELETE e
FROM dbo.Employees AS e
WHERE e.DeptNo IN
  (SELECT d.DeptNo
  FROM dbo.Departments AS d
  WHERE d.DeptName LIKE '%sales%') ;
```

I removed the `LCase()` as well. That is an Access function, not an SQL-Server one (thnx @Aaron). Add back (the equivalent `LOWER()`) if your database (or table) uses a case sensitive collation (the default is case insensitive so usually there is no need for such functions.)

Comment: And `LCase()` would need to be `LOWER()` anyway - the former does not exist in SQL Server.

Comment: @Aaron I missed that! So, the query probably has been converted form Access (that uses `*` as wildcard.)

Comment: For clarity, it's the *column* collation that should be inspected, not the database or table collation (there is no table collation, btw; Management Studio shows a collation in Properties, but it comes from the database setting).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DELETE
FROM Employees
WHERE DeptNo IN
  (SELECT DeptNo
  FROM Departments
  WHERE DeptName LIKE '%sales%')
```

The errors are caused by using the **DELETE *** syntax and * instead of **%** as a wildcard. You can find some useful examples here: [SQL: LIKE CONDITION](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)